# Get value of a td from a previous table row

Tags: jquery

I use a button to insert a new table row below the origin table row.

I do not want to duplicate the row with all values. I only want to copy some specific values.

Therefore, there are table datas `<td>`, which have the class 'ed-id'. The class is only used in one column.

**How can I get the value of the td of the previous row?**

I´ve tried it: But It do not work. val is empty

```
var myRow = $(this).parents("tr:last"),
    rowWithInput = myRow.prevAll(":has('.ed-id')").last(),
    val = rowWithInput.find(".ed-id").val();

console.log( val);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `prev()`:

```
var prevRow = $("button").closest("tr").prev(); // Will give you access to the row

prevRow.find("td.ed-id").html() // Or .text() will get you what's inside the td.
```

Note: Untested code!